# Save PIN assigned to a program in TACL Macro

Tags: process, macros, tandem

I need a way to save the process PIN (cpu,pin) of a new process when it's created. Something like this:

```
?TACL Routine
[#CASE [#EXCEPTION]
  |_BREAK|
      STOP [CURRENT_PROCESS]
      #UNFRAME
      #RETURN
  |_ERROR|
      #UNFRAME
      #RETURN
  |_CALL|
  |OTHERWISE|
      #UNFRAME
      #RETURN
]

#FILTER _BREAK _ERROR
#PUSH CURRENT_PROCESS

[SAVE_PIN CURRENT_PROCESS My_program]
#UNFRAME
```

I need this for "stop" the program when a user interrumpt the TACL Routine pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>.

Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was very simple.

Change

```
STOP [CURRENT_PROCESS]
```

For

```
STOP
```

Regards